# How can I tell how long a Jenkins job has been in the wait queue?

Tags: jenkins

In the case where a node goes down and the Jenkins master node is choking on a ton of jobs, is there a way to quickly know how long a job has been pending in the wait queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the main view, under **Build Queue** section, all the queued jobs are list. If you **hover** the mouse over them, it shows you all the extra information.

It will also show "*Waiting for x sec*"