# How can I know how long a Jenkins job has been in the wait queue after the job is finished?

Tags: groovy, jenkins

For the statistics, I want to see how long the job is in the waiting queue, therefore I can tune the system to make the job is run in time.

If the job is just in queue, it is possible to find in waiting queue in front page see [How can I tell how long a Jenkins job has been in the wait queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519485/how-can-i-tell-how-long-a-jenkins-job-has-been-in-the-wait-queue)

Or the `http://<jenkins_url>/queue/api/json?pretty=true`

Is it possible to check somewhere to get "Time waiting in queue" for the specific job after the job is finished ?

Will be nice if it can be gotten in public jenkins API.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

// got answer from colleague

It can be achieved by installing [Jenkins Metrics Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Metrics+Plugin), after it is installed, in the build result page, you will see

[image: time wait in queue]

**Jenkins REST API**: Then you can get wait time in queue from http://localhost:8080/job/demo/1/api/json?pretty=true&depth=2 . `queuingDurationMillis` is the data I wanted.

```
"actions" : [
{
  "queuingDurationMillis" : 33,
  "totalDurationMillis" : 3067
}
],
```

**Groovy script**: Also we can get this data in groovy via internal data, check below code in Jenkins Script console http://localhost:8080/script

```
job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem("demo")
build = job.getLastBuild()
action = build.getAction(jenkins.metrics.impl.TimeInQueueAction.class)
println action.getQueuingDurationMillis()
```

You can see the demo using docker by running below and open in browser for `demo` job

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 larrycai/jenkins-metrics
```

Comment: This does NOT work with Jenkins pipelines, the plugin reports zero queuetime even if jobs are waiting for hours.

Comment: FYI, the groovy script solution works for me with Jenkins pipeline (v2.73.x).

Comment: @sorin , I checked in my pipeline job, it works. (search for `queuingDurationMillis` is the json result.

Comment: @LarryCai do you know how to fetch `queuingDurationMillis` in the build step execution itself?

Comment: I guess you need post-build groovy script

Comment: For me the groovy example also does not work, as the job instance is null. Even though good hint, thank you.