# How can I send Jenkins job queuing times into Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, jenkins

I want to record the queue lengths of our Jenkins jobs and output to Elasticsearch. For this example, I would post something like

```
queue-duration:9.9
```

to elsasticsearch (among other data).

[image]

The API for the page doesn't contain this information. How can I get it, other than scraping the HTML? (jk)

Answer (score 2):

It should be part of the api, but I suggest you use groovy to determine extract it:
[How can I know how long a Jenkins job has been in the wait queue after the job is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735049/how-can-i-know-how-long-a-jenkins-job-has-been-in-the-wait-queue-after-the-job-i)